# IDeserializationCallback in XMLSrializer

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Is there a way to utilize the IDeserializationCallback interface with the standard xmlSerializer?  It does not appear to be supported in this context.

IDeserializationCallback works fine when used with the binary formatters.

Basicaly i want to do some calculation when de-serialization
e.g.:

```
public void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender)
{
    // After deserialization, calculate the age.
    Age = System.DateTime.Now.Year - (DOB.Year + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this interface is not used by the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) instead.